# How can I extract fields from JSON only when three matching fields are present?

Tags: json, ruby, hash, conditional-statements, field

I want to extract *employeid* and *result* where *deptcode*, *Name*, and *position* are present.

```
{
  "employeeid": 101,
  "result": {
    "deptcode": 0,
    "Name": "Henry",
    "position": "Administrator head."
  }
}
```

My current code is:

```
i = beginIndex
    temp = ""
    value = ""
    while i < endIndex
      temp = dataMap[i].to_s.split(":")[1].strip()
      value += "#{temp},"
      i += 1
    end
```

Comment: is the first snippet of an object or a string?

Comment: For the starters you might want to get rid of “xml” in title since it’s really confusing. Then you might want to stop abuse regexps with parsing structured entities. And, the last, but not least, you might want to share the error message you got and the problem you have experienced.

Comment: After all, there is no trail of any regular expression in the snippet as well.

Comment: Also, please don’t blame ruby for your lack of understanding, it’s ridiculous.

Comment: @mudasobwa  Please find the code attached below egx =/regpattern/  #This is the regex pattern 
    dataMap = Array.new
    dataMap = msg.split("\r\n") `msg is the value i am getting the result` 
    i=0
    length = dataMap.length
    while i< length
     if regx.match(dataMap[i]) == nil
    value = dataMap[i].split(":")[1]

Answer (score 0):

### Extract Fields by Hash Key

If you have a valid JSON string, you can covert it to a Ruby hash and access fields by key. Using [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) will enable you to only return a value if all fields are present. For example:

```
require 'json'

# Use a valid JSON string, or a native Ruby hash. We'll assume you're 
# starting with a JSON string, although the following would be a valid
# Ruby hash object without parsing if not wrapped in quotes. YMMV.
json = <<~EOF
  {
    "employeeid": 101,
    "result": {
      "deptcode": 0,
      "Name": "Henry",
      "position": "Administrator head."
    }
  }
EOF

# Convert the JSON above to a Ruby hash.
hash = JSON.parse json

# Extract fields when all keys are present.
[ hash['employeeid'], hash['result'] ] if
  hash['result'].keys.all? { |key| %w[deptcode Name position].include? key }

#=> [101, {"deptcode"=>0, "Name"=>"Henry", "position"=>"Administrator head."}]
```

This works fine with your corrected corpus. If you have an array of results, or a deeply-nested structure, then you'll need to do some additional coding to make it work. However, it works just fine with the refactored data given in the original post.